# Call of overload is ambigious

Tags: c++, c++14, overload-resolution

I am learning new C++ semantics and I got an error with this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

std::string foo(std::string str)
{
    return str + " call from normal";
}

std::string foo(const std::string& str)
{
    return str + " call from normal";
}

std::string foo(std::string&& str)
{
     return str + " call from ref ref";
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello World!";
    std::string res = foo(str);
    std::string&& res_ref = foo(std::move(str));
    std::cout << "Res ref = " << res_ref << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Str = " << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

> ```
> :23:30: error: call of overloaded ‘foo(std::__cxx11::string&)’ is ambiguous
>     std::string res = foo(str);
> ```

Why is the call ambiguous?

Comment: You have 3 `foo` functions, and it can't figure out which one you want to use.

Comment: but its double reference, standard function and const ref, why is that problem happening? When I comment first function declaration everything works fine, my Question is: why compiler cant chose whitch one use?

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know whether to call `std::string foo(std::string str)` or `std::string foo(const std::string& str)`? You call them in the exact same way

Comment: ok... so is there a way to force compiler to use standard method?

Comment: What is a *"standard method"* supposed to be? Also what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: by standard method I meant `std::string foo(std::string str){}` I'm trying to call each one of overloaded methods

Comment: No, the compiler is unable to distinguish between the two functions - and I can't think of any case where this would be useful in any way.

Comment: ok, thanks, I think it will do for me for now, but it is because both call same object or what?

Comment: You can read through the reference for overload resolution for more details: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution (short version: both methods rank the same when matching which one should be called)

Comment: you can differentiate between 3 different cases however: `T&` (mutable objects), `const T&` (constant objects), `T&&` (temporarys)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have;

```
std::string res = foo(str);
```

There are two viable candidates:

```
foo(std::string );         // #1
foo(std::string const& );  // #2
```

There are many, many steps in determining which function to choose when given multiple candidates. But in this case, both choices are completely indistinguishable - there is simply no preference in the overload resolution between `string` and `string const&` for an argument. Similarly, there is no preference between `string` and `string&&` for an rvalue argument, so your second call is also considered ambiguous.

Generally, the rules for preferring one function to another have to do with which one is more *specific*. For instance, given a function taking `string&` and one taking `string const&`, the former can only be called with non-const lvalue references to `string`, but the latter can be called with a whole bunch of stuff, so when both are viable, the former is preferred (specifically, due to [[over.ics.rank]/3.2.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2.6)). But in this case, anything that you could call `#1` with, you could call `#2` with. And anything you could call `#2` with, you could call `#1` with. So there isn't any reason to prefer one to the other.

You should simply remove that overload, leaving your two:

```
foo(std::string const& ); // #2
foo(std::string&& );      // #3
```

For lvalue `std::string`s, only #2 is viable. For rvalue `std::string`s, both are viable, but #3 would be preferred (by the general guideline that it is more specific - and specifically due to [[over.ics.rank]/3.2.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2.3)).

Comment: Back up your assertions with references.

Comment: @NickWestgate This isn't Skeptics.SE. Is there any statement in particular you question the validity of?

Comment: @NickWestgate : I appreciate the irony. ;-]

Answer (score -2):

Forget about the rvalue reference (string&&) one for clarity, and just pretend you're the compiler.

There are two functions defined:

1. foo(std::string str)
2. foo(const std::string& str)

Given str is a std::string you are asked to call:

```
foo(str);
```

Which function are you going to call, 1 or 2?

1. You can pass the str to foo 1.
2. You can pass a const reference to str (like a pointer) to foo 2.

In this case you could do either, so the compiler can't decide.

How does the compiler decide? There are rules about creating a list of candidate functions, what kind of type promotions or conversions can be performed on the arguments, and what constructors can be used to create the required argument. [Here is a simple overview](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~roger/cpp/week20.htm) from a course.

Comment: "You could do either" just means both are viable - it's not enough to say that it's ambiguous. You could do either if #1 were `foo(std::string&)` too, but that case wouldn't be ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for commenting about your downvote. I was just trying to keep it simple for a learner, and provided a link to a more detailed answer.

Comment: The issue is that you oversimplified it - your answer says that any time you have two viable candidates, the call is ambiguous. That isn't true.

Answer (score -2):

The ambiguity is between those two functions:

```
std::string foo(std::string str); // 1
std::string foo(const std::string& str); // 2
```

The way you read function names is from right to left. The English equivalents of these functions are:

1. `foo` is a function that takes an `std::string` parameter and returns `std::string`.
2. `foo` is a function that takes a `reference` to a `constant std::string` parameter and returns `std::string`.

respectively.

The only difference known to compiler between those two function signatures is to whether take a copy of `str` as it's parameter or an immutable reference to `str`. From compiler's perspective, those two functions don't have enough difference to have a preference to them during runtime.

In general, if it's not a primitive type (i.e int, char, short etc.), use reference instead of the type itself. For all for all intents and purposes, `std::string` is similar to `std::vector<char>` so no matter what the length of your string is, passing it by reference will always cost you `sizeof(pointer)` data transaction.

Comment: Would anyone kindly tell me where I was wrong (because of the downvote) so I can also learn from it :)